# Docker registering containers address as a host on Zookeeper

Tags: docker, dockerfile, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to implement a Docker container which can provide a two way communication. This container when comes up, registers itself on the zookeeper which is on LAN.

Dockerfile is provided below.

```
FROM java:7
EXPOSE 7100
ARG version
ENV version=$version
ARG port
ENV port=$port

RUN mkdir -p /cacheDir/services/live/prediction/p$port/$version/logs
RUN ls -tlr /cacheDir/services/live/prediction/p$port/

RUN mkdir -p /cacheDir/services/releases/prediction/p$port/$version/

RUN mkdir -p /cacheDir/services/predictionmodel
ADD target/predictionDependencies/* /cacheDir/services/predictionmodel/

ADD /target/prediction-0.0.13-SNAPSHOT.jar /cacheDir/services/releases/prediction/p$port/$version/prediction-0.0.13-SNAPSHOT.jar

ADD /target/instance.properties /cacheDir/services/releases/prediction/p$port/$version/instance.properties

ADD /target/logback.xml /cacheDir/services/releases/prediction/p$port/$version/logback.xml

RUN ls -ltr /cacheDir/services/live/prediction/p$port/$version/
RUN ls -ltr /cacheDir/services/releases/prediction/p$port/$version/
RUN ls -ltr /cacheDir/services/predictionmodel

ENTRYPOINT ["sh","-c","java -server -Xmx2g -Xloggc:/cacheDir/services/live/prediction/p${port}/${version}/logs/gc.log -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/cacheDir/services/live/prediction/p${port}/${version}/oom.dump -Dlogback.configurationFile=/cacheDir/services/releases/prediction/p${port}/${version}/logback.xml -Dlog.home=/cacheDir/services/live/prediction/p${port}/${version}/logs -Dlogback.debug=true -Dbroker.l^Ct=sv-kafka6.pv.sv.nextag.com:9092,sv-kafka7.pv.sv.nextag.com:9092,sv-kafka8.pv.sv.nextag.com:9092,sv-kafka9.pv.sv.nextag.com:9092 -jar /cacheDir/services/releases/prediction/p${port}/${version}/prediction-0.0.13-SNAPSHOT.jar $port /cacheDir/services/releases/prediction/p${port}/${version}/instance.properties /com/wizecommerce/services/$ZK_PATH"]
```

Command used to build the docker file.

```
docker build --build-arg version=v4 --build-arg port=7100 -t prediction:v4 .
```

The images creates successfully. Run Command used to register the service on the Zookeeper.

```
sudo docker run -p 7100:7100 -e ZK_PATH=qa -v ~/PredictionVolume/logs/:/cacheDir/services/live/prediction/p7100/v4/logs/  -t prediction:v4
```

The service comes up successfully, and the container is able to access the Zookeeper IP address and gets register there. However, the IP address with it which gets registers on the Zookeeper is really strange.

```
{"serviceEndpoint":{"host":"f88bf2357c97","port":7100},"additionalEndpoints":{},"status":"ALIVE","shard":0}
```

It looks as if the Zookeeper's host is registered with the container's MAC Address.

What I did, is that I manually changed the host address to my System's IP. On doing that, it successfully gets up and the process work fine as expected. 
I want that whenever I use my docker's run command, my system's IP should get register on the Zookeeper rather than container's IP.

Additionally, I also want to know what if I use my machine's IP address with the run command like this provided below. What exactly does this command means and also how it differs from the previous run command used.

```
sudo docker run -p x.y.z.a:7100:7100 -e ZK_PATH=qa -v ~/PredictionVolume/logs/:/cacheDir/services/live/prediction/p7100/v4/logs/  -t prediction:v4
```

where x,y,z,a lies in the IPv4 segments range (0-255).

Also, please let me know if any other information is needed which I may have missed out.
Thank you very much for the help!!!

Comment: the network in container is different from the host network。use --net=host may help

Comment: by using this, my system's hostname gets registered. I checked in the /etc/hosts file and it shows that hostname is mapped to my 127.0.1.1

Comment: due to your java implement。and your machine may have many ip（local ip or public ip，or more）

Comment: I dug into the code and found that the ip is getting resolved with the following line.
String ipAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();

Comment: I changed the /etc/hosts file and assigned my systems ip address to my hostname but that too didn't work.

Comment: 6 month ago，we did the same thing, and now wo comment these code , and manual pass ip as an env。InetAddress.getLocalHost() will return the right thing as we want

Comment: Any other way possible? Can't change the code as other dependencies may get impacted.